# What does 'gridSize' define in MarkerClusterer under 'option' object?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, markerclusterer

I am working on Google Maps and clustering of markers using MarkerClusterer library. What exactly does 'gridSize' parameter define in 'option' object? If it is the size of a cluster image in pixels, then how can I change it for different clusters in the same map?

I have tried using the MarkerClusterer library using the documentation provided at this link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering

It doesn't explain how to change and add 'option' object and how can we edit the option code according to our needs.

I would like you to help me with making the cluster image size different for different clusters on the same map.

Comment: from [one of the versions of the documentation](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/docs/reference.html):
**gridSize** number The grid size of a cluster in pixels.

Comment: @geocodezip I already visited that link but it doesn't explain in detail and only partially answers my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The MarkerClusterer library's [reference](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-markerclustererplus/blob/main/src/markerclusterer.ts) states:

> gridSize - The grid size of a cluster in pixels.

To use this option you can either add it in your MarkerClusterer options upon object creation:

```
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
  imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m',
  gridSize: 90
});
```

Or use the `setGridSize` method:

```
markerCluster.setGridSize(90);
```

And to check the current grid size of your markerCluster use `getGridSize`.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: thanks for your help, it solved the first part of the problem. I am still finding the solution for the second part i.e. different image for different cluster size.

Comment: Happy to help! :) As for this second question, do you mean using a different imagePath and gridSize for different MarkerClusterer objects? That's easily done as per the above code, just instantiate multiple objects with different image/grid size.